# Traditional panettone size & volume?

Tags: baking, cake

I'm planning to bake an "full size" panettone.  Does anyone know, for a full size panettone:

1. What is the diameter of the paper mould ?
2. What is the height of the paper mould  ?
3. How much dough (weight) goes in it ?
4. Extra question if 1-3 are not known, how much dough (weight) do you put per liter of mould capacity ?

I found a document somewhere on the internet last year in Italian explaining in detail the panettone process.  Think it was from the application when Italy wanted EU to give them trademark rights to the name 'Panettone'.  Sadly I can't find that doc anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For big (standard) panettoni typical values are:

1. Mould diameter of 17 cm (6.7 in).
2. Mould height of 11~13 cm (4.3~5.1 in).
3. Dough weight about 800 gr (1.7 lb).

   Albeit those values are not defined in [the Italian "standard"](http://www.uibm.gov.it/uibm/dati/Testo.aspx?load=info_tmpSingleUserList&loadOld=info_uno;708461;TradeMark&id=708461&table=TradeMark&loadTLS_ALS=), nor in [the howto](http://www.mi.camcom.it/upload/file/1335/667500/FILENAME/disciplinare_panettone_artigianale_2006.pdf). You can also find wider and lower moulds for the same dough sizes (or upt to 1 kg / 2.2 lb).

   You can find those measures [in most webs in italian](https://www.google.es/search?q=stampo%20panettone). Also, if you buy an already made *panettone* it will quite probably have those or very similar measures.
4. In general, you can use the formula:

   > Dough weight (gr) = 1,45 x Mould volume (cm<sup>3</sup>)

   Formula calculated empirically. You can [check some values in this italian forum](http://www.cookaround.com/yabbse1/showthread.php?t=147663&s=0637c07e8dc96cc20ae868874bdb621f&p=2486835#post2486835).

When you pour the dough in the mould it will only be filled up to ¼ or ⅓. It needs to rise a lot: above the upper part of the mould.

[Here you have a Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VFT8-LWO1c&feature=youtu.be) on making a homemade mould.
And [this page](http://lacocinadeile-nuestrasrecetas.blogspot.com.es/2008/10/molde-de-panettone-pan-dulce.html) shows you how to do the mould yourself. It's in Spanish, but [you can translate it automatically](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http://lacocinadeile-nuestrasrecetas.blogspot.com.es/2008/10/molde-de-panettone-pan-dulce.html&act=url).

---

Sidenote: Orthodox stress they should be done with *lievito naturale* (sourdough), not yeasts. Non orthodox italian standard accept only up to 0.01% of yeast.

Comment: If those values aren't in the "official" recipes that you've linked to, could you elaborate on where you got them?

Comment: Those are the sizes of typical moulds I've always found, both empty moulds or already made panetonni. I added a link in the answer. There are also some special moulds: wider and lower. But are not the *typical* ones.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  For future readers: I ended up getting 170x115 mm (diameter * height) Panettone moulds and put 1001 g of dough in it (that's 380g dough per litre of mould volume).  It took a while for the final rise (20h, it got too cold!) but had a wee dome on top in the end.  Texture (and taste!) was the same authentic Panettone I've seen before.

Comment: Could there be an error in answer #4 ? If volume = 1000 (1L) that gives dough weight 1.45*1000 = 1450g (which would probably fill the mould)

I ended up with "Dough weight = 0.38 * mould volume" so perhaps you intended to write 0.45 instead of 1.45 ?